# Execute a javascript code when ajax navigation completes in jQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am developing a jQuery mobile web app, which currently has two pages.

First, page 1 appears, and if user clicks on a link, page 2 opens with jQuery mobile ajax navigation system.

But, there is a problem. page 2 should run a javascript code when it loads, but jQuery mobile ajax navigation removes that script, even if I put `<script>...</script>` in `<div data-role="content">...</div>`... (javascript runs if I use `rel="external"` in my link in page 1, but If I want to use ajax navigation, javascript wouldn't load...)

How to run that javascript code when page 2 loads **with** ajax navigation system of jQuery Mobile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your page 2, add this:

```
$(document).bind("pageshow", 
  function(e) {
    // script here
  }
);
```

In jQuery mobile, page are being loaded using ajax and cached by default. When page 2 is displayed, "pageshow" event is triggered.

Comment: Where should I put this? in `<head>` or in `<div data-role="content">` ?

Comment: If you'll put this in the head tag, then it will be executed everytime a page is shown regardless of what that page is. In your case, you may put this inside <div data-role="content"> of page 2.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this in the head of your first page:

```
$( document ).on( "pagecreate", "#PAGEIDHERE", function() {
   //do something here
});
```

Then the script will only be called once the page is created. Or you can use 'beforecreate' etc.